# LIBGDX earclippingtriangulator messes up the indices

Tags: java, libgdx, polygon, triangulation

I am making some polygons in LIBGDX, using `ShapeRenderer` to draw the outline, and `PolyBatch` to fill it. The `ShapeRenderer` draws the polygon only relying on the `Verticies`, which it handles perfectly, while the `PolyBatch` uses the `Vertices` + `Indices` generated by the `EarClippingTriangulator`, and these polygons end up with some mistakes. This makes me draw the conclusion that the `EarClippingTriangulator` is at fault, though it have worked properly before, so there might be something with the way the `Vertices` are structured.

What should I do to make the `PolyBatch` behave properly?

Here's my polygon:

[image]

Comment: One fix would be to open that image in photoshop and delete the excess grey areas, other then that nothing we can do to clear things up for you without code..How do you use the `EarclippingTriangulator` and how are you drawing this to the screen would be a nice addition to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was apparently that there were some consecutive duplicate coordinates in the vertices, which created a bug when computing the indices